# Export records as xml

Tags: apex, soql, relationships, xmlnode

In salesforce I want to export records as xml and am stuck at getting child object records of same object. (Self relationship between interaction and I want to get Parent and its child)
Here is the code:

```
Dom.Document doc = new Dom.Document();
Dom.Xmlnode rootNode = doc.createRootElement('Interaction__c', null, null);
list<Interaction__c> interactionList = new list<Interaction__c>([select id, name,(select id, name from Interaction__r) from Interaction__c ]);
  for(Interaction__c eachParentInteraction : interactionList){
        Dom.Xmlnode parentInteractionNode = rootNode.addChildElement('Interaction', null, null);
      parentInteractionNode.addChildElement('Interaction_ID',null,null).addTextNode(eachParentInteraction.ID);
        parentInteractionNode.addChildElement('Interaction_Name',null,null).addTextNode(eachParentInteraction.name);
  }
    //for(Interaction__c eachChildInteraction : eachParentInteraction.Interaction__c){       //<---- HERE AM STUCK PLEASE SOMEONE HELP ME
    //    Dom.XmlNode childInteractionNode = parentInteractionNode.addChildElement('Child_Interactions',null,null);
    //}
    system.debug(doc.toXmlString());
```

Comment: Why not just use Outbound Messages?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create map where key is parent id and value is list of child elements, then for each parent element you can create nested lines:

```
Dom.Document doc = new Dom.Document();
Dom.Xmlnode rootNode = doc.createRootElement('Contact', null, null);

list<Contact> Contacts = 
    new list<Contact>([select id, name from Contact where createddate = today]);

map<id,list<Contact>> parentIdToChildrenMap = new map<id,list<Contact>>();

for (Contact con :[select name, id, contact__c from contact where contact__c in :Contacts]) {
    if (parentIdToChildrenMap.containsKey(con.contact__c)) {
        parentIdToChildrenMap.get(con.contact__c).add(con);
    } else {
        parentIdToChildrenMap.put(con.contact__c,new list<Contact>{con});
    }
}

for(Contact parent : Contacts) {
    Dom.Xmlnode parentNode = rootNode.addChildElement('Parent', null, null);
    parentNode.addChildElement('Parent_Id',null,null).addTextNode(parent.Id);
    parentNode.addChildElement('Parent_Name',null,null).addTextNode(parent.Name);

    if (parentIdToChildrenMap.containsKey(parent.id)) {
        for (Contact child :parentIdToChildrenMap.get(parent.id)) {
            Dom.XmlNode childNode = parentNode.addChildElement('Children',null,null);
            childNode.addChildElement('Child_Id',null,null).addTextNode(child.Id);
            childNode.addChildElement('Child_Name',null,null).addTextNode(child.Name);
        }
    }
}

system.debug(doc.toXmlString());
```

Result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Contact>
    <Parent>
        <Parent_Id>0033600000MIRWdAAP</Parent_Id>
        <Parent_Name>Alice</Parent_Name>
        <Children>
            <Child_Id>0033600000MIRZNAA5</Child_Id>
            <Child_Name>Cheshire Cat</Child_Name>
        </Children>
        <Children>
            <Child_Id>0033600000MIRWeAAP</Child_Id>
            <Child_Name>Queen</Child_Name>
        </Children>
    </Parent>
</Contact>
```